# Background color of Col-md-9 based on category-A

Tags: css, colors, nested, dependencies, selector

I want to change the background color of Col-md-9 based on the category of the blogpost

```
/* makes the colom blue whatever the category */
.cat-md-9 {background-color: blue;}

/* makes only the text area (not the entire colom) of category-A blue */
.category-a {background-color: blue;}
```

I now want to make the entire colom blue if category equals A.

Is that possible?

[Here's the link to the page](http://landvanmogelijkheden.nl/2016/12/21/prinsen-prinsessen-training/) (text is in dutch but that's not important). 
as you can see, it's not the entire column and that's a little ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to understand for me but, from what I understood you want to make the background of the blog post blue if the `col-md-9` is in a specific category.

To that, by looking at the way you are doing it now you can do this

```
col-md-9 .category-leer {
    background-color: rgba(52,210,147,0.2);
}
```

By using that, the `.category-leer` class will only have a blue background if it is inside a `col-md-9`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mahan_F, I will try to make it more clear. The code you shared does color the area around Category-leer only when it's inside Col-md-9, however, I would like to color Col-md-9 when Category-leer is inside col-md-9.

```
If col-md-9 CONTAINS category-leer {
    col-md-9 {
        background-color: rgba(52,210,147,0.2);
    }
}
```

A case statement would be even better since I have 4 categories I want to color-code.